# Form submission unexpectedly navigates to another screen

Tags: react-native

I created 4 different screens with a [bottom tab](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator) menu that I use to navigate.

One of my screens has a form and when I submit it, the app seems to render back to the first screen listed inside my tab navigator. I don't explicitly call for this behaviour anywhere and was expecting to stay on the same screen (the Weight Tracking screen). Any clues as to why this is happening?

My tab navigator:

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const AppStack = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator tabBar={(props) => <BottomMenu {...props} />}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Dashboard" component={DashboardScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Weight Tracking" component={WeightTrackingScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Period Tracking" component={PeriodTrackingScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Food Tracking" component={FoodTrackingScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

My Weight-Tracking Screen:

```
const WeightTrackingScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <WeightInputForm></WeightInputForm>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}
```

My Weight Input Form:

```
const WeightInputForm = () => {
  const {userToken, setIsLoading} = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [numberInput, setNumberInput] = useState('');
  const [dateInput, setDateInput] = useState(new Date());
  const [showDatePicker, setShowDatePicker] = useState(true);

  const handleNumberInputChange = (value) => {
    if (/^\d{0,3}(\.\d{0,1})?$/.test(value) || value === '') {
      setNumberInput(value);
    }
  };

  const handleDateInputChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
    setShowDatePicker(Platform.OS === 'ios'); // Hide on iOS immediately, on Android, let the user confirm
    if (selectedDate) {
      setDateInput(selectedDate);
    }
  };

  async function createWeight() {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/weights', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Authorization": userToken,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "weight": {
            "weight_number": numberInput,
            "date": dateInput
          }
        })
      });
  
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log('Data:', data);
  
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }

    setIsLoading(false);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          keyboardType="numeric"
          value={numberInput}
          onChangeText={handleNumberInputChange}
          placeholder="Enter Number"
        />
      </View>

      {showDatePicker && (
        <DateTimePicker
          value={dateInput}
          mode="date"
          display="default"
          onChange={handleDateInputChange}
        />
      )}


      <Button title="Submit" onPress={createWeight} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

My bottom menu (probably irrelevant but I'll include it just in case)

```
const BottomMenu = ({ navigation }) => {
  const handleOptionPress = (routeName) => {
    navigation.navigate(routeName);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.menuContainer}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.menuItem} onPress={() => handleOptionPress('Weight Tracking')}>
        <Text>⚖️</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.menuItem} onPress={() => handleOptionPress('Period Tracking')}>
        <Text></Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.menuItem} onPress={() => handleOptionPress('Food Tracking')}>
        <Text></Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

(oh boy, apologies for the large pics - not sure how to shrink them. This is before submit and after submit)

[image: Before Submit] [image: After Submit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call to `setIsLoading` will re-render everything below `AuthContext.Provider`. The navigator's first screen is `DashboardScreen` and thus the default one and it will be shown when re-rendering happens.

```js
const {userToken, setIsLoading} = useContext(AuthContext);
...
async function createWeight() {
  setIsLoading(true);
...
}
```

Move the loading state to `WeightTrackingScreen` to avoid re-rendering the whole stack.

```js
const {userToken} = useContext(AuthContext);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
...
async function createWeight() {
  setIsLoading(true);
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, TIL about using context values == re-rendering everything below the context provider!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't seem to have any logic or issue to navigate to another screen after submission. However, the navigation behavior might be influenced by the navigation stack or state.

Try this:

```
const WeightInputForm = ({ navigation }) => {

  async function createWeight() {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {

      const data = await response.json();
      console.log('Data:', data);

      // Add this line to navigate back to the WeightTrackingScreen after successful form submission
      navigation.navigate('Weight Tracking');

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }

    setIsLoading(false);
  }

  
};
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your input :) I tried adding the "forced" navigation as per your suggestion, and while it doesn't produce any errors, the end result remains the same (which makes me think the navigation back to the Dashboard screen must be happening after this)